# Dataframe pattern edition by two columns condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I would like to keep only the rows of a `Dataframe` with the following condition: the intervals(included) in which the beginning condition is `col1 = 0, col2 = 1` and the interval end `col1 = 0, col2 = 2`.

## Sample data

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({'id':['id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id2','id2','id2','id2','id2']
                  ,'col1':[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1],'col2':[1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2]})
```

This would look like this:

```
    col1 col2 id
0   0   1   id1
1   1   2   id1
2   1   2   id1
3   0   1   id1
4   1   2   id1
5   0   2   id1
6   0   1   id1
7   1   2   id1
8   1   2   id1
9   0   2   id1
10  0   1   id1
11  1   2   id2
12  0   2   id2
13  0   1   id2
14  1   2   id2
15  1   2   id2
```

We can realise that in a general way there are "blocks" or intervals with `0-1,0-2` in `col1,col2`. However, sometimes we dont have an (0-2) ending so the last 1-2 of the id would be the closing expresion of the block, we would have to edit this row (replace col1 1 = 0) in order to have in the same format than other blocks. See row number 2 and 15(desired change).

## Sample Output.

```
   col1 col2 id 
0   0   1   id1 
1   1   2   id1 
2   0   2   id1 
3   0   1   id1 
4   1   2   id1 
5   0   2   id1 
6   0   1   id1 
7   1   2   id1 
8   1   2   id1 
9   0   2   id1 
10  0   1   id1 
11  1   2   id2 
12  0   2   id2 
13  0   1   id2 
14  1   2   id2 
15  0   2   id2
```

Now each block starts  with (0-1) and ends(0-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `apply`

```
In [303]: def chg_last(x):
     ...:     x.iloc[-1] = 0
     ...:     return x

In [304]: df.col1 = (df.groupby((df.col2.shift().eq(2) & df.col2.eq(1)).cumsum())
                       .col1.apply(chg_last))

In [305]: df
Out[305]:
    col1  col2   id
0      0     1  id1
1      1     2  id1
2      0     2  id1
3      0     1  id1
4      1     2  id1
5      0     2  id1
6      0     1  id1
7      1     2  id1
8      1     2  id1
9      0     2  id1
10     0     1  id1
11     1     2  id2
12     0     2  id2
13     0     1  id2
14     1     2  id2
15     0     2  id2
```

---

Details

Identifying groups

```
In [308]: (df.col2.shift().eq(2) & df.col2.eq(1)).cumsum()
Out[308]:
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     2
7     2
8     2
9     2
10    3
11    3
12    3
13    4
14    4
15    4
Name: col2, dtype: int32
```